# Catastrophic Assertion Failure on Blackberry Simulators with BlackBerry versions 5.0 or above

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Using the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse me and my team mate installed the BlackBerry JDKs version 4.7, 5.0, 6.0. But when it comes to running project, I get a very serious error. If I build the project with version 4.7 then it runs alright with the existing simulators.But when I build the project with the version 5.0 or 6.0 then the simulator doesn't even start properly.

It starts and immediately shows the error "Catastrophic Assertion Failure" and then it closes automatically. The same error comes with all the existing simulators like 8900, 8520, 9550, 9700(for version 5.0) and simulators 9800(for version 6.0) .Only one simulator 9630 works for the BlackBerry version 5.0 but its damn damn slow when its attached with debugger.I have uninstalled and reinstalled all the stuff but still the same problem.

My project should be written in version 5.0 coz it needs the Database API.But I am not able to run it.My team mate has got none of the errors like mine.The JDK is working perfectly fine.I have compared all the settings in his system with mine but still the same issue.I have to fix this bug at any cost.

These are the version details I am running in my system.

Java version 6 update 22

BlackBerry Java Plug-in:      1.1.2.201004161203-16

BlackBerry Java SDK:              6.0.0.29

BlackBerry Java SDK:              5.0.0.25

BlackBerry Java SDK:              4.7.0.57

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers:  1.2.2.20100216-1730

Eclipse Platform:             3.5.2.M20100211-1343

EPP Java Package:             1.2.2.20100216-1730

Android DDMS:                     0.9.6.v201002051504-24846

Android Development Tools:    0.9.6.v201002051504-24846

Thought if the Android Version details would be helpful.

Now I thought of downloading the BlackBerry Simulator 9105 and integrate it to Eclipse.Hope it works. But I need an answer very urgently.Please help me.I have already searched the web for any helpful answers but didnt find anything relevant to my Project Development issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have struggled hard enough to get a solution for this, but at last i got one solution. Download the BlackBerry Simulator 9650 from the BlackBerry Developers Zone and install it on to your system. Restart the Eclipse IDE and try to run your project again.This time set the run configuration , and choose the installed simulator BB 9650.

Save and run the project .It will run successfully. But the only case is while debugging its sometimes bit sow.

Is the Debug mode related to the System's RAM in any way? Coz i have a low RAM value, i think that might be the issue. Kindly help me with ur answers.